# Concat distinct values in a for-each

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've run into a problem and i'm looking for a quick fix. I have an xml from which i take a some values:

```
<root>
<item>
<property1>value</property1>
<property2>value</property2>
<property3>value</property3>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</root>
```

I'm making a variable to use after using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/item"><xsl:value-of select="concat(property1,';')"/></xsl:for-each>
```

But i've ran into a problem when too many items, the variable gets too big (over 255 characters). So i was thinking of taking only the unique values (unique property values).

Any simple way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test the stylesheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="group" match="property1" use="."/>

<xsl:variable name="unique_properties">
    <xsl:for-each select="//property1[count(. | key('group', .)[1]) = 1]"><!-- this selects unique values -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="$unique_properties"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Worked with the Key. Thanks very much, and sorry for the late response, it was a really busy day :)

Comment: Although i've changed it a bit ... :)                                <xsl:key name="ItemByProperty" match="root/item" use="Property1"/>

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="root/item[generate-id(.)=generate-id( key('ItemByProperty', Property1)[1] ) ]"><xsl:value-of select="concat(Property1,';')"/></xsl:for-each>